# On Xubuntu, my windows suddenly have no control buttons on the upper right hand corner

Tags: xubuntu

Since windows cannot be resized or closed, I have to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> most of the time.  Also, I cannot use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch from one window to another. Both problems prevent me from using more than one window effectively.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently some fault has killed `xfwm4`, a program that manages windows and draws the decorations around them. If you have a terminal open, type `xfwm4 --replace` and hit enter. Also, logging off and on might restore it.